# Changing background color of navbar

Tags: html, css

I have tried using id's for each individual navbar options but the background color wont change only the text in the navbar changes.
My required outcome is to get a background color for each navbar option.(Note this is a bootstrap template I am editing). [This is a link to my files with what I have tried so far.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onHio2PW7XJnhZ6TwuJcgoJ23mqCeCH7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please move your sample to the snippet editor or a codepen, not many of us are going to be willing to open third-party .zip's etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add styling inline with html using `style="background-color:blue;"`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the bootstrap template then you can use the following classes

```
class="bg-primary" // to add blue background.
.bg-secondary // to add gray.
.bg-success   // to add green etc.
```

to change the text use `class="text-primary"` and other classes.
check out more [here(colors)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/)  and [here (navbar)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/).